# How does pip decide which many linux wheel to use?

Tags: python, linux, scipy, pip, travis-ci

Binary many-linux wheels are now supported:

https://github.com/pypa/manylinux

Specifically I would like to install the many linux wheel for scipy on Travis, using the trusty beta operating system. The wheels are listed here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.17.1

I get:

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.17.1.tar.gz (12.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 12.4MB 100kB/s
```

Instead of:

```
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (39.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 39.5MB 37kB/s
```

So, in order to fix this, I would like to know, how pip determines which wheel to download and install. And yes, I did update pip to version 8.1.2 which supports binary many linux wheels.

Specifically, I am **not** interested in alternative solutions, just answer the question, if you can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need pip 8.1 or later and a linux distribution that is based on glibc (and not musl libc as alpine linux for instance).

EDIT: the [function](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7ec0fa5142466f8402bb866a1dcfb8ca6ffdc66b/src/pip/_internal/utils/compatibility_tags.py#L120)  `pip._internal.utils.compatibility_tags.get_supported()`  should return the list of supported [platform tags](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7ec0fa5142466f8402bb866a1dcfb8ca6ffdc66b/src/pip/_internal/utils/compatibility_tags.py#L120) in order. Pip prefers wheel tags that appear earlier in this list over tags that appear later.

Also may I kindly suggest you to use python 3.5 instead of 2.7 ;)

Comment: Yes, as soon as I can confirm our tech-stack works with 3.5 I will switch to 3.5. I have pip 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04. Also, you didn't answer the question, as requested.

Comment: It seems that the 2.7 mu variant has not been uploaded (only the m variant is available for 64bit linux). It might be an oversight of the scipy release manager. Python 3 does not have this issue because there is a single way to handle unicode.

Comment: I just had another look, and it seems like `scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (md5, pgp)` was uploaded yesterday. Restarting the build to check if it works now.

Comment: Thanks also for the `get_supported()` hint, that did the trick.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `m` and `mu` variants?

Comment: Wide or narrow unicode. It's a build option in python 2 that has an impact on its ABI. On python 3 the concrete unicode impl is defined at runtime depending on the unicode string object contents and this is transparent both for the user and the compiled extensions.

Comment: There's no way to get wheels for the scipy working on alpine due to `musl libc`, is there? Compiling scipy and pandas from scratch is quite painful.

Comment: You could probably build you own but there is no community effort to maintain those packages.

Answer (score 8):

Since pip version 19.3,
`TargetPython.get_tags()` returns
the supported [PEP 425 tags](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#overview) to check wheel candidates against ([source](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/6500e595601b8cb4ce597b9f7a71aaf82441c1f8/src/pip/_internal/models/target_python.py#L82)). The tags are returned in order of preference (most preferred first).

```py
from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
target_python = TargetPython()
pep425tags = target_python.get_tags()
```

The class [TargetPython](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/21.1.3/src/pip/_internal/models/target_python.py) encapsulates the properties of a Python interpreter one is targeting for a package install, download, etc.

Comment: Nice, just had to add this to display the result:

    `from pprint import pprint
    pprint(pep425tags)`

Answer (score 4):

For pip 10 you'll need to run:

```py
from pprint import pprint
import pip._internal
pprint(pip._internal.pep425tags.get_supported())
```

Comment: I'm getting the error, `AttributeError: module 'pip._internal' has no attribute 'pep425tags` with python 3.9.1, pip 21.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

So, the correct answer is that pip has a list of supported tags and will try to match those. `pip.pep425tags.get_supported()` will list the tags for your platform and will also use that list to match manylinux binary wheels.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I want to install `dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl`

```bash
python -m pip install dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl
```

However, it shows `ERROR: dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. I think maybe it relates to the version of the OS. Mine is Ubuntu 18. Then I tried to change the number of 31 to 24 in `dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl`. It works.

```bash
cp dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl dmlab2d-1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_24_x86_64.whl
```

I think `31` is for Ubuntu 20, and `24` is for Ubuntu 18.

> PEP 600 has been designed to be "future-proof" and does not enforce specific symbols and a specific distro to build. It only states that a wheel tagged manylinux_x_y shall work on any distro based on glibc>=x.y. The manylinux project supports:
>
> - manylinux_2_24 images for x86_64, i686, aarch64, ppc64le and s390x.
> - manylinux_2_28 images for x86_64, aarch64 and ppc64le

See the instruction: https://github.com/pypa/manylinux